# Semantic UI Custom Rule Validation for Select Drop-Down Field

Tags: forms, validation, semantic-ui

I am trying to add some custom logic to my semantic ui validation but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Basically, when the user selects "Yes" from the drop-down, I would like to make the "input_field" mandatory. If the user selects "No", the "input_field" becomes optional and the form can be submitted.

I tried searching for examples and followed some code from the Semantic Ui website but can't figure out what I am missing. Any advice would be appreciated as I am on a deadline for a project I am working on.

Form:

```
<div class="ui dimmer">
    <div class="ui huge text loader">Loading</div>
  </div>
<form method="post" action="" class="ui form" autocomplete="on">                 
    <div class="ui segment">
        <div class="ui two fields">
            <div class='field'>                                   
                <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                    <input type="hidden" class="selectOption" name="select">
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <div class="default text">Select an option</div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item" data-value="Yes">Yes</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="No">No</div>
                </div>
                </div>                                     
            </div>
            <div class="field">                                   
                <input id="input_field" name="input_field" type="text"/>                                        
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
<button id="submit" class="ui green button" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

Validation:

<script>
$('.ui.form').form({
    keyboardShortcuts: false,
    on: 'blur',
    inline: 'true',
    fields: {
    selectOption: {
            identifier: 'select',
            rules: [
                {
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please select an option'
            }]
    },
    input_field: {
            identifier: 'input_field',
            depends: 'select',
            rules: [
                {
            type: 'empty',
            prompt: function() {
                $('.select').on('change', function() {
                if( this.value == 'Yes') {
                    return "Custom Validation";
                }
                return false;
            }).trigger("change"); 
            }
            }]
    }
    },
    onSuccess: function() {
        $('.ui.dimmer').dimmer('show');
    },
    onFailure: function() {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}            
); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution for this! It might not be the best answer but it works and does what I am looking for.

```
<div class="ui dimmer">
    <div class="ui huge text loader">Loading</div>
  </div>
<form method="post" action="" class="ui form" autocomplete="on">                 
    <div class="ui segment">
        <div class="ui two fields">
            <div class='field'>                                   
                <div class="ui selection dropdown">
                    <input type="hidden" class="selectOption" name="select">
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                <div class="default text">Select an option</div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item" data-value="Yes">Yes</div>
                    <div class="item" data-value="No">No</div>
                </div>
                </div>                                     
            </div>
            <div class="field">                                   
                <input id="input_field" name="input_field" type="text"/>                                        
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
<button id="submit" class="ui green button" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$('.ui.form').form({
    keyboardShortcuts: false,
    on: 'blur',
    inline: 'true',
    fields: {
    selectOption: {
            identifier: 'select',
            rules: [
                {
                type: 'empty',
                prompt: 'Please select an option'
            }]
    }
    },
    onSuccess: function() {
        $('.ui.dimmer').dimmer('show');
    },
    onFailure: function() {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}            
); 

$('.selectOption').on('change', function() {
if ( this.value == 'Yes' ) {
  $('.ui.form').form('add rule', 'input_field', ['empty', 'integer']);
  $('.ui.form').form('add prompt', 'input_field', 'Enter an integer');
}
if ( this.value == 'No' ) {
  $('.ui.form').form('remove prompt', 'input_field');
  $('.ui.form').form('remove rule', 'input_field');
}
}).trigger("change");

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the validation rule by extending Semantic UI setting rules.
See below example:

```
$.fn.form.settings.rules.dependsOnFieldValue = function (value, dependFieldValue) {
   
   var identifier = dependFieldValue.split('[')[0];
   var dependValue = dependFieldValue.match(/\[(.*)\]/i)[1];

   if( $('[data-validate="'+ identifier +'"]').length > 0 ) {
      matchingValue = $('[data-validate="'+ identifier +'"]').val();
   }
   else if($('#' + identifier).length > 0) {
      matchingValue = $('#' + identifier).val();
   }
   else if($('[name="' + identifier +'"]').length > 0) {
      matchingValue = $('[name="' + identifier + '"]').val();
   }
   else if( $('[name="' + identifier +'[]"]').length > 0 ) {
      matchingValue = $('[name="' + identifier +'[]"]');
   }
   
   return (matchingValue !== undefined)
        ? !( dependValue.toString() === matchingValue.toString() && value === '')
        : false
      ;
};
```

Then in the form validation initializer you will pass the desired values as below:

```
$(".ui.form").form({
    fields: {
           
         select: {
            identifier: 'select',
            rules : [
                {
                    type : 'empty'
                }
            ]
        },
        input_field: {
          identifier : 'input_field',
          rules      : [
            {
                type : 'dependsOnFieldValue[select[Yes]]',
            }
          ]
        },
    ...

     }
});
```

Notice that we pass the `<select>` identifier (in this case also called select) within the first `[]` and then the value that we want to see to make the `input_field` mandatory ("Yes" in this case).